# Is it possible to convert UTF-8 code to the correct characters in R?

Tags: r, utf-8

I web scraped data that I could only collect the UTF-8 character code names. I'm aware there are packages out there to convert regular character vectors to UTF-8 code. But are there packages to convert UTF-8 code to the correct characters?

So for example I've got

```
%22%E2%80%93 This isn%27t desirable%21 %E2%80%93%22
```

When i'd want

```
"– This isn't desirable! –"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strings are [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). This encoding can be undone with the [URLdecode](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/URLencode) function:

```
> z <- URLdecode("%22%E2%80%93 This isn%27t desirable%21 %E2%80%93%22")
> cat(z)
"– This isn't desirable! –"
```

Comment: If you are on Windows, you'll also need to let R know the data is UTF-8 (otherwise it assumes Latin-1). You can do `Encoding(z) <- "UTF-8"` after the `URLdecode`